# Getting a Pending Migrations error on my rails app after deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, webfaction

I've been trying to deploy my site to Webfaction from Github via Capistrano 2, and I've definitely made some progress.

Here's my repo: https://github.com/jaronoff/new_site

I'm trying to deploy to josharonoff.com

I finally have my deploy.rb the way I want it, and I checked cap deploy:status works fine, I run cap deploy and it works fine, but I for some reason am getting this error even though I've restarted via the deploy.rb file.

error:

```
ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError at /
Migrations are pending; run 'bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development' to resolve this issue.
```

When I run the cap deploy, the output I get says that it's deployed correctly, and even does the db migration to the rails env of production... so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the output from the console when I run cap deploy:

```
  * 2014-02-13 14:43:39 executing `deploy'
  * 2014-02-13 14:43:39 executing `deploy:update'
  ** transaction: start
  * 2014-02-13 14:43:39 executing `deploy:update_code'
updating the cached checkout on all servers
executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:jaronoff/new_site.git master"
command finished in 2251ms
* executing "if [ -d /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 3b7d990f32d1fa2bdb7153d1c00548fec510eb33 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q -b master git@github.com:jaronoff/new_site.git /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 3b7d990f32d1fa2bdb7153d1c00548fec510eb33; fi"
servers: ["web432.webfaction.com"]
[web432.webfaction.com] executing command
command finished in 1956ms
copying the cached version to /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344
* executing "cp -RPp /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/shared/cached-copy /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344 && (echo 3b7d990f32d1fa2bdb7153d1c00548fec510eb33 > /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344/REVISION)"
servers: ["web432.webfaction.com"]
[web432.webfaction.com] executing command
command finished in 233ms
* 2014-02-13 14:43:44 executing `deploy:finalize_update'
* executing "chmod -R -- g+w /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344 && rm -rf -- /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344/public/system && mkdir -p -- /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344/public/ && ln -s -- /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/shared/system /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344/public/system && rm -rf -- /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344/log && ln -s -- /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/shared/log /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344/log && rm -rf -- /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344/tmp/pids && mkdir -p -- /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344/tmp/ && ln -s -- /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/shared/pids /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344/tmp/pids"
servers: ["web432.webfaction.com"]
[web432.webfaction.com] executing command
command finished in 254ms
* executing "find /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344/public/images /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344/public/stylesheets /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344/public/javascripts -exec touch -t 201402131943.44 -- {} ';'; true"
servers: ["web432.webfaction.com"]
[web432.webfaction.com] executing command
** [out :: web432.webfaction.com] find: `/home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344/public/images': No such file or directory
** [out :: web432.webfaction.com] find: `/home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344/public/stylesheets': No such file or directory
** [out :: web432.webfaction.com] find: `/home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344/public/javascripts': No such file or directory
command finished in 195ms
* 2014-02-13 14:43:45 executing `deploy:create_symlink'
* executing "rm -f /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/current &&  ln -s /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344 /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/current"
servers: ["web432.webfaction.com"]
[web432.webfaction.com] executing command
command finished in 198ms
** transaction: commit
* 2014-02-13 14:43:45 executing `deploy:restart'
triggering before callbacks for `deploy:restart'
* 2014-02-13 14:43:45 executing `deploy:migrate'
* executing "cd /home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/releases/20140213194344 && rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"
servers: ["web432.webfaction.com"]
[web432.webfaction.com] executing command
command finished in 1939ms
* executing "/home/jaronoff/webapps/ac_site/bin/restart"
servers: ["web432.webfaction.com"]
[web432.webfaction.com] executing command
command finished in 3217ms
```

Any help or anything would be greatly appreciated. I've gotten pretty far today just by trial and error.

Thanks in advance!!
~Josh

Comment: Have you tried to run `rake db:migrate` right on the server?

Comment: Why aren't you using `cap deploy:migrations`? I would try removing this custom recipe and use the default. Also it looks like your production app is trying to run in development mode.

Comment: I did try to run db migrate but I get an error saying it couldn't find bundler/setup. It's strange because I have the gems installed and those work fine.

Comment: Mikey, I ran deploy:migrations and it did the same thing that deploy: migrate did. Are you saying take out the before restart do deploy:migrate and instead do deploy:migrations?

Comment: What are the differences between those two?